# PHP ignores php.ini timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.5

I did `locate php.ini` in CL.

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

In both of those files I defined timezone as next:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Africa/Cairo"
```

I restarted PHP. I restarted Apache. I restarted even the server.

`phpinfo();` tells me /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini is the correct file. Even when I check the phpinfo() ouput it tells me my timezone is Africa/Cairo (UTC+02:00), but doing `date('d-m-y G:i:s')` with PHP always return UTC time.

What am I doing wrong..? I've read every documentation I've found... do I have to somehow recompile php with new settings? I even don't know what I mean by that, just desperate.

```
php --version
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:23:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: try to put: `date.timezone=Africa/Cairo`

Comment: Are you sure there is no call to `date_default_timezone_set()` anywhere else in your code that overwrites your configuration?
What does happen when you call `date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Cairo")` directly before you call `date('d-m-y G:i:s')`?

Comment: You can check your timezone using `echo date_default_timezone_get();`